# Can't change series edgeColor in highCharts after chart is drawn

Tags: highcharts, 3d

I'm attempting to change edgeColor property for a series in a 3d column chart after the chart is drawn, based on some user input (like selecting a certain series).  I was able to do this was a 2d column chart using the borderColor property.  My data loading snippet looks like this:

```
$.each(seriesDataArray,function(i,val){
   console.log (val);
   chartDetails.series.push({ "size" : val.datasetSizeVerified , "data" : val.data});               
};
```

And I'm trying to modify the edgeColor in a function later on in code:

```
function highlightChartSeries(currentTableDisplayIndex){
        if (myChart){
            $.each(myChart.series,function(i,val){                                  
                val.edgeColor = "green" ;                               
                val.redraw();                                                    
            });                

            myChart.series[currentTableDisplayIndex].edgeColor = "red";               
            myChart.series[currentTableDisplayIndex].redraw();                                

        } 
}
```

Again, this works great in 2D with a column chart using the borderColor property.  I can set the edgeColor in the original series object during chart construction, and that edgeColor is reflected in my original graph.  However, I can't change it later.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To add (or change) some value to existing series, you should use *Chart.Series* function called *update()*, and pass to it new configuration options object, because it is a function specially created to executing actions like that. Please take a look at code below:

```
chart.series.forEach(series => {
  series.update({
    edgeColor: 'black'
  })
})
```

I prepared for you [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_s/692zz950/) how to use that function.

Best regards!

Comment: Perfect, Daniel.  Thank for the time.  And the demo!